# Sencha Touch app appears blank in browser

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have a really simple Sencha Touch 2.0.1 app made with Sencha Architect 2.0.0: a list of items loaded from a local json file. If I export it to an APK and install it on my droid, it displays perfectly. However, when I try to preview it in my browser it appears as a blank white screen.

I have tried it in both Chrome and Safari. Safari displayed it perfectly the FIRST time I loaded the page, but I have never gotten it to work again. I tried clearing internet data, to no effect.

Since I have no idea what could be causing this issue, I'm going to post a link to my code rather than list EVERYTHING here. Thanks.

.xda archive: http://www.mediafire.com/?9k2341dtblyq4e1 
.zip file: http://www.mediafire.com/?07s6pfa734l3ewi

Perhaps another piece of relevant information is that I'm using WAMPSERVER 2.2 with default config, and I've had this problem with most of my other apps (that use list views) as well.

The CityBars tutorial from Sencha works completely in Chrome, and loads the title bar in Safari but does not load any items to click on. http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2-0/#!/guide/first_mobile_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things :

Add a these to your list's config :

```
  fullscreen:true,
  layout:'fit',
```

Add this to your application's config (app.js) :

```
launch: function() {
  Ext.Viewport.add({
    xclass: 'MyApp.view.MyNavigationView'
  });
}
```

Then, the url in your store should probably be :

```
url: 'data/data.json',
```

I made it work with these config. Hope this helped

[[Download]](http://d.pr/f/USyG)

Comment: I don't see a fullscreen config to set anywhere, but I added a controller and added a launch function to it, with your code. That was the only change - it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: The list still doesn't display when I load it from the internet (rather than file system), but I will post that in a new question.

Comment: Do you get any error message form the Web Inspector / Firebug

Comment: Yes I do TDeBailleul, I included it in the new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905325/sencha-touch-list-doesnt-load-data-in-browser

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit late but my answer might help somebody else: make sure that the "autoLoad" property of the store you are using in your DataView is "ticked" (this is if you are using Sencha Architect).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was in fact ticked for my app, but this could very well be an issue for someone else.