# Sencha Touch list doesn't load data in browser

Tags: list, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have a really simple Sencha Touch 2.0.1 app made with Sencha Architect 2.0.0: a list of items loaded from a json file online ([here](http://listtest.webs.com/data.json)).

If I export it to an APK and install it on my droid, it displays perfectly. However if I try it on Chrome or Safari, they say 'Loading...' then display the word 'empty' where the list should be.

I get this error in Firebug: `GET http://listtest.webs.com/data.json?_dc=1344620739517&page=1&start=0&limit=25 x 166ms` (where that 'x' is circled in red, meaning the request failed I guess). The Response field is blank, even though that's a valid URL.

Here are links to my full code. Thanks for any help you may have.

.xda archive: http://www.mediafire.com/?11ism2o13gkcz27 
.zip file: http://www.mediafire.com/?f76by4d445vb6zu

Extra info: I'm using WAMPSERVER 2.2 with default config, and I've had this problem with most of my other apps as well. The [CityBars tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2-0/#!/guide/first_mobile_app) from Sencha works completely in Chrome, and loads the title bar in Safari but does not load any items to click on.

Even a comment that says "that code worked/didn't for me" would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a PHP file + JsonP store instead, based on the source code from [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP).

It works perfectly. No special configs needed, just a default JsonP store with URL set to my new PHP file. For some reason nothing displays when I 'load data' manually, but it works in the browser and that's all that matters.