# Unable to preview Extjs app in browser by Sencha Architect?

Tags: extjs, browser, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I am developing a large scale extjs app in Sencha Architect. While working with it suddenly I was unable to get preview of the app in browser. It shows blank page. I have checked that framework & CSS have been loaded. But the app is shown. There is no error in Architect too.

I am unable to find the problem caused.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks much!

Comment: Take a look here:
[Sencha Touch app appears blank in browser][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904012/sencha-touch-app-appears-blank-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you used [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (or other debug tools) in your browser? Its likely a minor code issue which is throwing out your page rendering, using a debug suite will help to quickly identify and resolve the issue.

Alternatively, it may be a result of your app not being instantiated correctly (if you aren't using a viewport, or haven't explicitly rendered the main view)